# Excel crash when setting setting PivotField filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have the following filters attached to a Pivot Table:

1. Row Type
2. Identifier
3. RBDM
4. Master
5. Sub

When attempting to set Master using .CurrentPage = "TEST" it crashes, despite the fact that the value exists.

Upon investigation, I noticed the value appears twice in the PivotFields.PivotItems list, which might be the issue. When filtering using the GUI I also notice the duplication, but the system allows me to choose both the numbers.

I've attempted to iterate through the PivotItems and manually set visibility, but it only ever selects the first occurrence of the value.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what is going on?

Been playing around with it for the better part of a day without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering the page filters seems to have fixed the problem.

There was an almost duplicate record for Master, except for one field which identified it as a header to be ignored. I had this header identifying field as a lower page filter, which for some reason caused it to be ignored.

This caused crashes and other strange behaviours when attempting to programatically change the CurrentPage.